# googleMap JavaScript

Tags: javascript, polyline

How to draw a polyline between 2 points when user clicks a submit button, and reset it when user clicks reset button.
i used this code to draw a polyline in plotting function() and called it using onclick() but that is not working, can please any one tell me how we call the function,and draw a polyline

```
<script>
function initialize()
{
....}

    function plotting()
     {
       var stratapps = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(17.447246,78.362029),
            new google.maps.LatLng(37.50905,-121.974659),

        ];
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: stratapps,
          strokeColor: "#FF0000",
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2,

        }); 
             flightPath.setMap(map); 
       }  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', plotting);

    <button value="plot" onclick="plotting();">Plot</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A few quick tips for you: 1. Don't put your email address, all answers will be provided on this site for you and others to benefit from. Nobody will contact you directly with a solution. 2. Include as many details about what you are trying to do as possible. For instance: what version of the Google Maps API are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: function plotting()
 {
   var apps = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(17.447246,78.362029),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.50905,-121.974659),
        
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path:apps,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,

    }); 
         flightPath.setMap(map); 
   }  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', plotting);

Comment: i tried to call this function from button click, onclick="plotting();", but the function is not working

Comment: Edit your question to include these details, making sure to use the Code button for the javascript (it looks like {} in the toolbar above the text area).